# I am trying to accessing the object through React facing error

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetching a object using component but facing an error :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

ListRendering.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import List from './List';
export default class ListRendering extends Component {
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state={
            user:["John","Paul","Max"],
            employees:[
                {id:1,name:"jonhy",email:"johny@gmail.com"},
                {id:2,name:"steve",email:"steve@gmail.com"},
                {id:3,name:"angel",email:"angek@gmail.com"}]
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        const employe=this.state.employees.map((items)=><List obj={items} />);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.user}</h1>
                <List />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

List.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function List(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>id: {props.obj.id}</p>
            <p>name:{props.obj.name}</p>
            <p>email:{props.obj.email}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Facing this issue on List.js it is not identifying properties of object like id,name and email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of this code.

```
 <div>
  <h1>{this.state.user}</h1>
  **<List />**
 </div>
```

You need to replace `<List />` with `{employe}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, ?. operator is checking nested data and renders it when there is data, if not it will not give error

```
<div>
    <p>id: {props.obj?.id}</p>
    <p>name:{props.obj?.name}</p>
    <p>email:{props.obj?.email}</p>
</div>
```

it is same as below:

```
<div>
       <p>id: {props.obj ? props.obj.id: null}</p>
        <p>name:{props.obj ? props.obj.name: null}</p>
        <p>email:{props.obj ? props.obj.email: null}</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: error is gone but not picking up the values that i passed using props

Comment: You didn't use it inside return so thats why it will not render it. Instead of writing <List/> inside return, just pass {employee} in div

Answer (score 0):

You're Here passing the **List** Component with no props in it (`<List />`)
so instead pass the **employe** variable like so

```
<div>
  <h1>{this.state.user}</h1>
  {employe}
</div>
```